# Formatting Data URI in HTML5 and Javascript to paste into Microsoft Office / Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, image, outlook, data-uri

I have an image that is formatted as a data URI and displayed in an HTML page. I can copy that image and paste it into some programs (e.g. Microsoft Paint, Photoshop, etc.)

But I want to paste the image into a new email in Microsoft Outlook, and when I try to do that nothing gets pasted in. Based off the research I've done, it looks like Outlook doesn't support data URIs. Is there a way to format a data URI so the content in the clipboard is formatted in an Outlook-friendly way so I can paste the image in? For reference, the snipping tool in Windows 7 behaves as expected - I can take a screenshot, copy it to clipboard, paste it into a new email and it appears correctly.

Other things to note:

- I've tried copying and pasting [the image from this example](https://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/0eac306e4dac2114c752) that uses toBlob(), still doesn't work
- The data URI in HTML looks something like this:

  ```
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
  ```
- The end goal is a format similar to `<img src="name.png" />` or something similar that I can copy and paste directly into Outlook. Unclear what format the clipboard data needs to be in for Outlook to accept it, but clearly some programs work (e.g. copying from Chrome or using the Snipping Tool.

Thanks in advance!